# JS/React multiple cookies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

ok, so I guess I'm missing something very simple here, but can't manage to store more than one cookie with this function:

```
function safe_item(name) {
document.cookie = 'item name:' + name;
}
```

It works exactly as expected, but when a new cookie is created, the previous one just disappears :/

Comment: You have to append all the cookies into a single string. Be careful to not slice out parts not related to your own app. Eg, you'll find a google analytics chunk in alot of cookie strings as well that you don't want to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `document.cookie` only accepts a single string as value;

So, instead of `document.cookie = 'item name:' + name;`, do this `document.cookie += 'item name:' + name;`